# Controlling what is put in the legend

Tags: matlab

I want to add a red cross and a cyan dot to the legend (I won't want the line to be in the legend) however this puts the line and a red cross in the legend. How could I remove the line and only have a red cross and blue dot there?

```
x = -1:0.01:1;
y = @(x) x.^2;
hold on
plot(x, y(x), '.-')

for x = -1:0.01:1;
    if (x < 0)
        plot(x, y(x), 'rx');
    else
        plot(x, y(x), 'c.');
    end
end
hold off
legend('red cross', 'cyan dot')
```

produces the figure

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bb9XA.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which set of data have to be shown in the legend, by specifying their handle as input of the `legend` function.

You have to modify your code as follows:

```
x = -1:0.01:1;
y = @(x) x.^2;
hold on
p1=plot(x, y(x), '.-')

for x = -1:0.01:1;
    if (x < 0)
        p2=plot(x, y(x), 'rx');
    else
        p3=plot(x, y(x), 'c.');
    end
end
hold off
legend([p2 p3],'red cross', 'cyan dot')
```

that is: get the handle of the two plot withi the `if` section (the ones only plotting the cross and the star markers, then specify them in the call to `legend`.

By doing this, the legend for the first plot (`plot(x, y(x), '.-')`) is not shown.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get the same thing, it is because we are both just adding handles without realizing the plot functions are inside for loops.

Comment: @BrianLynch not sure I understand your second comment, In the code proposed by the OP, probably the first `plot` instruction is redundant. If you specify the handle in the `legend` call, it will show only them; if you, for example, call it as `legend(p2,'red cross')` the legend will only show the red cross despite there are three calls to `plot`.

Comment: Yea was thinking about that too. But why does the plot contain blue lines and not only red x's and cyan .'s?

Comment: @BrianLynch because at the beginning of the script there is `p1=plot(x, y(x), '.-')`

Comment: Oh man sorry I must need some more coffee, I was thinking that line should be removed when it is only the legend entry we are removing. My bad! :P

Answer (score 0):

You can do this based on the instructions [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/controlling-legends.html). But overall, it reduces to this command, where `h` is the handle to the graphics object you want to remove from the legend.

```
set(get(get(h1,'Annotation'),'LegendInformation'),'IconDisplayStyle','off')
```

So for your code, it would look like this:

```
x = -1:0.01:1;
y = @(x) x.^2;
hold on
h1 = plot(x, y(x), '.-')

for x = -1:0.01:1;
    if (x < 0)
        h2 = plot(x, y(x), 'rx');
    else
        h3 = plot(x, y(x), 'c.');
    end
end

set(get(get(h1,'Annotation'),'LegendInformation'),'IconDisplayStyle','off')

hold off
legend('red cross', 'cyan dot')
```

Comment: Oh I like il_raffa's answer better, didn't know you could do it that way!